Spring Boot Clean Authentification
I'm a bit confused about the different ways to manage authentication for my rest Spring Boot API. I wanted to start with a simple opaque token, with a login route that gives a token. I store the token in my database associated with a user (Manage sessions).
But I see on the internet that this approach is not very popular, people seem to use jwt instead (Why not). But I see that even with jwt, people do it in many different ways.
For example, some use org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt, others add an external dependency to spring boot with io.jsonwebtoken (jjwt-api, jjwt-impl, jjwt-jackson), why?
I'm confused because I see that there's Spring Security, Spring Session, Oauth2 Client, oauth2 Authorization Server... I don't know what to use, preferably as natively as possible with spring, to manage my authentication convienently.
Do you have any recommendations?
Thanks

Your questions are too abroad but I will try to give you some hints.
I don't know what is OAT Token but regarding REST api securisation this is how you should go.
First thing first, REST apis should be stateless, that means after the end of a request the api should not keep any state, even about the authenticated user/client. That is why authentication is delegated to a third-party, commonly an authorization server(AS) using the OAUTH2 protocol. Depending on your needs, the AS can be configured to generate different token formats most often JWT or Opaque Token, JWT is the commonly used. Now how to secure your apis, what Spring components do you need to protect your apis?
1- To create an AS you have the Spring Authorization Server project.
2- To projetct your apis you have the Spring Resource Server. You can use any AS you want, and use Spring Security Oauth2 features to protect your apis.
Start first by learning Oauth2 before diving into Spring Security configuration.

I agree with the statement in @akuma8 answer that you should get some OAuth2 basics before diving into Spring Security configuration. I maintain some OAuth2 essentials that can be of help for that. Reading the OAuth2 and OpenID specs is something useful too.
Regarding the "clean" OAuth2 usage, it is generally recommended that REST APIs are configured as stateless resource servers. Stateless means here that there is no session on the resource server and that requests are authorized with Bearer tokens (actually, state is not removed, it is just moved to the clients which have to store tokens). This makes scalability and fault tolerance super easy to implement on resource servers.
The downside is that OAuth2 resource servers can be queried only by OAuth2 clients (services that can acquire, store, and refresh tokens). But as it is now recommended that tokens are not sent to front-ends (it should remain on servers you can trust) the OAuth2 client(s) should not be the front-end(s).
The recommended solution is to use an OAuth2 BFF: a middleware on the backend to act as the OAuth2 client and bridge between traditional session-based authorization (with the front-ends) and token-based authorization (with REST APIs). I wrote an article for that on Baeldung.
About the authorization server, you really don't have to use Spring Security's one. I almost always prefer something "ready to use" like Keycloak or cloud solutions (Auth0, Amazon Cognito, etc.). In my opinion, Spring Authorization Server is rather easy to implement only when all users come from external IDPs (Google, Facebook, Github, etc.), and no GUI is needed for users & clients administration.
